# what is the significance of Eigen values of autocorrelation matrix?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, matlab, image-processing

I am  trying to find auto correlation matrix of an image to get Harris corners.Paper I am referring suggest that if eigen  values of auto correlation matrix are large the point will be corner point.so how does corners are related to eigen values of auto correlation matrix?

Comment: (As a rather unimportant side mark, it's called "eigenvalues" - it is a term like "matrix"; "Eigen" does not refer to a mathematician or the like)